# Additional source directories using Geany

Tags: programming, c++, geany

I'm using Geany in Ubuntu as an IDE for a C++ Project, and I want to use some external libraries (from Webots). However, I don't find the option to specify additional library paths (as one can find in Code::Blocks or Netbeans). Must I specify the paths manually as a build option? If so, how do I do it? I'm not exactly an expert at this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can specify additional libraries in the `Project Properties (Project -> Properties)` as shown in the picture

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the place. However, I need to specify both the libraries for the linker and the include directories for the compiler. I've been using -L for the first and -I for the second, and it compiles successfully, but it doesn't build (some "undefined references" errors). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the complete command which you are using?

Comment: `g++ -Wall -c "src/%f" -L "/usr/local/webots/lib/libController.so" -L "/usr/local/webots/lib/libCppController.so" -L "../../lib/OPKinematics/lib/libOPKinematics64.a" -L "/usr/local/webots/resources/projects/robots/darwin-op/libraries/darwin/libdarwin.so" -I "../../lib/OPKinematics/include" -I "../../lib/include" -I "/usr/local/webots/include/controller/cpp" -I "/usr/local/webots/include/controller/c" `

Comment: Can you try and replace all the relative paths with absolute paths?

Comment: Already tried it, still doesn't build. I'm getting several errors of the type:

`main.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to webots::DarwinRobot::savePosition()'`

Comment: I downloaded and installed webots. Can you give me a sample program, which I can try to compile on Geany?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8322/discussion-between-joao-andre-and-thefourtheye)

Comment: Sure. Try http://www.mediafire.com/?ttujd0xvt6y20qu. It has a working makefile included.